How can I reduce the space between the steps and the connecting line in my flexbox layout?
I'm working on a web layout where I need to display a series of steps connected by a line. I've set up a flexbox layout with spheres representing each step and a line connecting them. However, there's too much space horizontally between the line and the spheres, while I want to bring the line closer to the spheres. Ideally it should be only a few pixels between them.
Here's the HTML and CSS code I'm using:


.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>



I suspect the problem lies in my .line CSS class.
I didn't manage to resolve the problem and I'm starting to doubt it is even possible to do what I'm trying to do. I tried moving the line using position: relative but I can't adjust the length of the line that way. I also tried using position: absolute but I just can't get the result I'm expecting and I don't really know how to position the line using absolute values correctly.

I would suggest trying to absolute position the labels underneath the numbers instead of trying to absolutely position the lines. That will preserve the line length being determined by the distance between circles while also allowing the length of the label to be whatever without adjusting the spacing around it's parent container.

The line is as wide as it can be with basic flexbox, if you put an outline on the step elements you will see the problem.



.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>



In addition, the label is forcing the steps to be wider than the 50px of the "sphere" as you can see in the snippet above.
An option is to force the step to only be as wide as the sphere, which we can do by setting the width to 0 but adding a min-width of 100%.



.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
  z-index: 2
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>



This leaves us with the problem of the label which we can solve by forcing nowrap and adjusting to recenter the text with a transform.


.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
  z-index: 2
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  translate: -50%;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>




If you add a specific unique selector to each sphere element you can use pseudo class selectors ::after and ::before as nth-of-type does not work on classes. Then you can style a line to make up the gap between the line and the sphere element. The problem here is it looks wonky if you zoom the browser and it's not as accurate in length and will not scale.


.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* step gets a position of relative for the positioning 
   of absolute pseudo element grand child 
*/
.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

/* style the line relative to the parent -> `step` position
   position/width is a bit loose here but it works in a static situation
*/
.one::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  left: 3rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

/* style the line relative to the parent -> `step` position
   position/width is a bit loose here but it works in a static situation
*/
.two::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <!--/ added a unique class of `one` /-->
    <div class="sphere one">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <!--/ added a unique class of `two` /-->
    <div class="sphere two">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>



Another way would be to use the pseudo tags on the line element. We can get a lot more accurate with placement and lengths using a little bit of JS to get the left and right positions of the adjoining elements; sphere and line, use a css variable to set the left and right position respectively of each filling line. Use that same css variable to also set the width of the line.
We set the pseudo elements ::before and ::after on the line element and use calc() along with the css variable to set the width and positions.


// get the sphere and line elements
const spheres = document.querySelectorAll('.sphere');
const line = document.querySelector('.line');

// create a method to calculate the two lines lengths/widths
const fillGap = (els, el) => {
  // subtract the first spheres right positon from the lines 
  // left position to get the length of the firstline
  const firstLine = `${Math.ceil(el.getBoundingClientRect().left - els[0].getBoundingClientRect().right)}px`;
  // subtract the lines right positon from the second spheres 
  // left position to get the length of the secondline
  const secondLine = `${Math.ceil(els[1].getBoundingClientRect().left - el.getBoundingClientRect().right)}px`;

  // set the css varaible and pass them to the document root using setProperty()
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--firstWidth', firstLine);
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--secondWidth', secondLine);
}

// call the method and pass int he elements
fillGap(spheres, line);
.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

/* use a css variable to get position and width of each pseudo ::before and ::after element of `line`
   use calc on top to get the center as we are relavtive to the `steps-container` elements positioning
*/

.line::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* get half of the height of the line and calc it with half the height this will be center */ 
  top: calc(50%-1.5px);
  /* mulitply by -1 to move left of elements left position by the width coming from JS */
  left: calc(var(--firstWidth) * -1);
  /* set width to the variable coming from JS */
  width: var(--firstWidth);
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%-1.5px);
  right: calc(var(--secondWidth) * -1);
  width: var(--secondWidth);
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>



Another example using JS would be to just use one pseudo element and make it the adjoining line. Using a method and JS this could be much more scalable.


const spheres = document.querySelectorAll('.sphere');
const line = document.querySelector('.line');

const fillGap = (els, el) => {
  const lineStart = `${Math.ceil(el.getBoundingClientRect().left - els[0].getBoundingClientRect().right)}px`;
  const width = `${Math.ceil(els[1].getBoundingClientRect().right - 
    els[0].getBoundingClientRect().left - 
    (els[1].getBoundingClientRect().width * 2))}px`;
  
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--lineStart', lineStart);
  document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--width', width);
}

fillGap(spheres, line);
.steps-container,
.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sphere {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%-3px);
  left: calc(var(--lineStart) * -1);
  width: var(--width);
  height: 3px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.label {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="steps-container">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">1</div>
    <div class="label">First step label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="sphere">2</div>
    <div class="label">Second step label</div>
  </div>
</div>




I liked Paulie_D's elegant solution and explanation, but it slightly shifts the label position and changes the bounding box of the steps.
here is an alternative approach using JavaScript:


function connect() {
    const sphereWidth = document.querySelector('.sphere').offsetWidth;
    const gap = 3;  // small gap between the spheres and the line 
    document.querySelectorAll('.steps-container').forEach((steps) => {
        const spaces = Array.from(steps.querySelectorAll('.step')).map((step) => (step.offsetWidth + sphereWidth) / 2 + gap);
        const line = steps.querySelector('.line');
        line.style.left = spaces[0] + 'px';
        line.style.right = spaces[1] + 'px';
    });
}

window.addEventListener('resize', connect);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', connect);
.steps-container,
.label-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.step {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sphere {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: white;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.line-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 3px;
    top: 25px;
}

.label {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
<div class="steps-container">
    <div class="step">
        <div class="sphere">1</div>
        <div class="label">First step label</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-container">
        <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <div class="sphere">2</div>
        <div class="label">Second step label</div>
    </div>
</div>



Explanation
HTML: Wrapped the line inside a line-container to maintain the width and allow for absolute positioning.
CSS: Positioned the line absolutely within the line-container.
JavaScript: Calculates the space between the circles and positions the line dynamically. Event listeners ensure the line adjusts on window resize and when the DOM content is loaded.
I hope it helps you.
